# Is it safe to run GPG tools in x11?

Tags: x11, security, password, cryptography

Given the relative (anyone with my present user permissions can swipe scancodes) ease of keylogging in an x11 environment, should I run GPG tools only in the TTY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "swipe scancodes", but I would say **No. Do not use GPG tools with sensitive private keys when you are not confident that the system integrity is up to par.**

Perhaps I'm too sensitive/paranoid, but if keylogging the X environment is a concern, why wouldn't the TTY also have integrity concerns? Maybe we don't have enough info. Are you running a remote X session over the network?

Comment: Any program running in x11 can listen to scancodes from the keyboard. On the TTY, only the foreground program can.